# My Iframe heights is always cut off no matter what code I've tried

Tags: iframe, height, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've tried several ways of coding this and have had all sorts of trouble getting my entire iframe to show up. I don't want to use scrollbars so I've coded those out. Here is the app on my page:

https://www.facebook.com/HorseRacingRadioNetwork/app_315312098503969

And here is the current code I've used:

```
<head>
   ....



     <script type="text/javascript">
       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

     //Der folgende Code ändert die Grösse des iFrames alle 100ms
     FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(100);

     };
     (function() {
     var e = document.createElement('script');
     e.async = true;
     e.src = document.location.protocol +
     '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
     }());

     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

But I've researched and tried what seems like a million things and yet I always get the same result? Any suggestions would be extremely helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to call FB.CANVAS.setAutoResize before loading the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing firebug shows me when I go to your page tab is a JS error,

> TypeError: document.getElementById("fb-root") is null
>
> document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);

And the way JavaScript (usually) works, is that any error stops the execution of the rest of the script or any other scripts for the document.

*Please learn how to use your browser’s error console!*